# regex for a link

Tags: php, regex

I have a text with 'a' tags there. I have to add some new tags and attributes.

It looks like this:

```
'Some test <a href="site">here</a>. Yet <a href="site2">another</a> test.'
```

Now I have to get:

```
'Some test <noindex><a rel="nofollow" href="site">here</a></noindex>.'
'Yet <noindex><a rel="nofollow" href="site2">another</a></noindex> test.'
```

Any fast ways to do that with php? Thanks.

Comment: You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. But you can do regular expression replaces in PHP with well structured markup. It's a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would cover most real world cases:

```
$text = 'Some test <a href="site">here</a>. Yet <a href="site2">another</a> test.';

$regex = '%(<a\s)(.*?</a>)%i';
$replacement = '<noindex>$1rel="nofollow" $2</noindex>';

preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Bearing in mind that HTML parsing with regular expression is a bad idea (you should use something like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) instead), this should do it:

```
$str = 'Some test <a href="site">here</a>. Yet <a href="site2">another</a> test.';
echo preg_replace('/<a(.+?)<\/a>/', '<noindex><a$1</a></noindex>', $str);
// Some test <noindex><a href="site">here</a></noindex>. Yet <noindex><a href="site2">another</a></noindex> test.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to give the DOMDocument ([docs](http://us.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php)) version, since the conventional wisdom says "Don't use RegEx on HTML!!".  Well, that's a fine thing to say, but then what!? Well, here you go:

```
    // create a new DOMDocument
    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    // load the string into the DOM
    $doc->loadHTML('Some test <a href="site">here</a>. Yet <a href="site2">another</a> test.');

    // since we are working with HTML fragments here, remove <!DOCTYPE 
    $doc->removeChild($doc->firstChild);            

    // likewise remove <html><body></body></html> 
    $doc->replaceChild($doc->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $doc->firstChild);

    //Loop through each <a> tag in the dom and wrap it with <noindex>
    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        $parent = $link->parentNode;
        $ni = $doc->createElement('noindex');
        $ni->appendChild($link->cloneNode(true));
        $parent->replaceChild($ni, $link);
    } 

   echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Check it out here: http://codepad.org/ANi93sBj

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace('~<a.*?href=(.*?)>(.*?)</a>~msi', '<noindex><a rel="nofollow" href=$1>$2</a></noindex>', $html);
```